# Ant Design Popconfirm confirm on [ENTER]?

Tags: reactjs, antd

How do I make Popconfirm perform the confirm action on [ENTER] key?

[image: And Design Popconfirm widget]

```
render() 
{
    const { deleteTask, props } = this.props


    const onConfirm = (e) => 
    {
      deleteTask(
      {
        id: props._id,
      })
    }

    return (
      <Popconfirm placement="topRight" title="Delete row?" onConfirm={onConfirm} okText="Yes" cancelText="No">
        <Button type="default">
          Delete
        </Button>
      </Popconfirm>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

To check if user has clicked `Enter` key:-
First, `<Button onClick={(event) => this.clickHandler(event)} >Click</Button>`

```
clickHandler = (event) => {
  if(event.key === 'Enter'){
    // do some stuff
  }
}
```

This code works with every library as this is vanilla javascript.

Comment: I want this behavior on the Popconfirm ok button, not on the Button itself. Added my code, maybe that clarifies what I want.

Answer (score -3):

If you what to perform any action using enter key word for that you need to keep the entire input fields within form and submit the form.

```
handleSubmit = ()=>{
 // submit logic here
}

<form onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.handleSubmit() }} >

 // input fields here
 <button type="submit" />
   </form>
```